# PowerPoint slide to display data from MySql database? How?

Tags: mysql, vba, odbc, powerpoint

I have a powerpoint presentation running continuously.

Is there a way to update one of the slides of this presentation automatically with data from a MySQL database?

Specifically, the data I need is to be returned from mysql stored procedure.

PROCEDURE `sp_MatrixTotals`(IN p_start_date DATETIME, IN p_end_date DATETIME, IN p_start_date1 DATETIME, IN p_end_date1 DATETIME)

Comment: what do you mean by 'from stored procedure'? But yes, you could do so. Search for ADO or ADODB. There are a lot of examples everywhere, mostly for MS Excel. But they could be quite easily adopted for any other MS Office application.

Comment: KazJaw, I have added more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First download connector **[ODBC](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/)** with this complement installed, configure a New odbc source (**MySql**) and select the **database** which you need.

So, in your Power Point you can insert a **Excel Spreadsheet**, an object will be inserted, 
make a right click on the Excel Object and select the option:

```
Spreadsheet Object > Open
```

Then **Excel application** will be open, in this window you can select:

```
Data > From other sources > From Microsoft Query
```

The asistant helps to select the column that you need with a **Sql query** or select each column, as well.

> > But, if you can install other tools, use [**MySql for Excel**](http://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/windows/excel/) with this tool you can call any object from mysql (views and **routines included**) read [**this post**](https://blogs.oracle.com/MySqlOnWindows/entry/how_to_guide_to_importing) from Oracle.